# Eclipse refers which TNS file

Tags: java, eclipse

I am able to connect to database using PL/SQL developer.
But, when I am not able to connect to database using `DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl, idUser, password);`

I am getting this error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:673)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:715)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:564)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
```

Comment: Following `TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor` you need to check your `databaseUrl`.

Comment: Someone pls delete this question

Comment: jdbc:oracle:thin:@<IP address>:1521:<service id>

Comment: jdbc:oracle:thin:@<IP address>:1521/<service id>

Comment: this solved the problem